# How to draw path on google map as I am moving?

Tags: android

I am trying to draw path in google map. I am able to draw a path between start point and end point but I want to draw path as I am moving. Please help me to draw path as I am moving on google map.

Thanks 
Monali

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Register [LocationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html) and in method [onLocationChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html#onLocationChanged%28android.location.Location%29) draw a path between start point and the point that has come.

```
    private void addLocationListener(LocationListener locationListener) {
    LocationProvider locationProvider = getLocationManager().getProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    getLocationManager().requestLocationUpdates(locationProvider.getName(), LOCATION_UPDATE_INTERVAL,
            LOCATION_UPDATE_MIN_DISTANCE, locationListener);
}

private LocationManager getLocationManager() {
    return (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
}

private void startGpsListening(Location start) {
   this.startLocation = start;
   addLocationListener(new MyLocationListener());
}

private Location startLocation = new Location("");

private class MyLocationListener extends LocationListener {

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "New location has come: " + location);
        // draw path between startLocarion and this location
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I tried to do same like this..but didn't get success..please provide some sample piece of code...Thanks

Comment: May be u have your gps turned off ? Have u got any location from it?

Comment: @Flavio, Can you please look at this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745913/update-location-marker-and-draw-path-on-google-maps-when-walking-driving-in-andr

Comment: @Flavio, i am having same functionality but i got a small problem in that. Please if you have any idea help me.

Comment: i want send those updated latlng cordinates to server, how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Collect the latest N points in array. Each time when you update the array, redraw all values. Use Overlay to draw the line on it.