# How do I draw line on path travel led by me on Google map in android?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have started doing one experiment which contain drawing a line on Google map. In my application I am able to load the map which gives my location on map. But I want to draw line as I am moving on map. I have seen similar type of questions on this forum but didn't get any idea. please give me reply 
Thanks,
Onkar

Comment: The Same question was answered today http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578934/how-to-draw-path-on-google-map-as-i-am-moving