# Update Location Marker and draw path on Google Maps when walking/driving in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, gps, directions

I want to create a functionality like Google Maps. I want to update my location marker whenever a person start walking/driving. I am thinking of using onLocationChange method of LocationListner but I am not sure. I also like to draw the path with updating location on the Google Maps.

All suggestions are most welcome.

ItemizedOverlay:-

```
public class LocationOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem>{

    private List<OverlayItem> myOverlays;
    Path path;
    static int cnt = -1;
    public LocationOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {
        super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
        System.out.println("Normal...");
        myOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
    }


    public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
        System.out.println("Add Overlay called");
        myOverlays.add(overlay);
        populate();
            cnt++;
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        return myOverlays.get(i);
    }

    public void removeItem(int i) {
        myOverlays.remove(i);
        populate();
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return myOverlays.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, final MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {


           if (shadow) {
            paint.setDither(true);
            paint.setColor(Color.RED);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
            paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(4);

            path = new Path();
            Point point1 = new Point();
            Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
            if (myOverlays.size() > 1) {

                System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>");

                for (int i = 0, j=i; i < myOverlays.size(); i++) {
                Point point1 = new Point();
                Point point2 = new Point();
                projection.toPixels(myOverlays.get(i).getPoint(), point1);

                System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>");

                projection.toPixels(myOverlays.get(j++).getPoint(), point2);
                System.out.println("Point == " + j);

                path.moveTo(point2.x, point2.y);
                path.lineTo(point1.x, point1.y);
                canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
                super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
            }   
            }
        }
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
    }
}
```

**NOTE - draw method gets called multiple time for single locationChanged.**

**EDIT :-**

I am able to draw the route whenever there is any location changed event fire but I am facing a small problem there. Its also drawing path from root every time. I want that from last place it should start drawing the path (i.e connecting from last to next location). I am attaching one image for better understanding.

[image]

From the image you can see that the starting point is also connected to last point. I don't want this. Any idea on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current location can be easily drawn with [MyLocationOverlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/maps/MyLocationOverlay). What you need to do - is to add this overlay to your MapView. Something like:

```
mapView.addOverlay(new MyLocationOverlay(context, mapView));
```

The default location dot will be drawn automatically and will be updated as soon as you move

With route it is a bit trickier, but still there is no rocket science in there. What you need to do - is to extend Overlay class and implement `draw()` logic. You need to keep track of GeoPoints you travelled and project them on a map (in your overlay's `draw()` you can ask your mapView for a `Projection` instance - `getProjection()`. You can use this projection to map GeoPoints to your map coordinates).
As soon as you have list of GeoPoints - you can create a [Path](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html) and draw this Path on a Canvas

The simplified example how to draw path on a map (there are some custom classes I use in my project, but you should get an idea):

```
Path path;

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, final MapView mapView, boolean shadow)
{
    Projection proj = mapView.getProjection();
    updatePath(mapView,proj);
    canvas.drawPath(path, mPaint);
}

protected void updatePath(final MapView mapView, Projection proj)
{
    path = new Path();

    proj.toPixels(mPoints.get(0).point, p);
    path.moveTo(p.x, p.y);

    for(RouteEntity.RoutePoint rp : mPoints)
    {
        proj.toPixels(rp.point, mPoint);
        path.lineTo(mPoint.x, mPoint.y);
    }
}
```

Comment: The default location dot will be drawn automatically and will be updated as soon as you move bu How it will be updated? I know that by implementing LocationListner it is done but i want to know that how its updating? Is it based on requestUpdateLocation of LocationManager? And at the time of update its calling onLocationChange method right?

Comment: internally - yes. It is using either GPS or Network to receive last known location and when location gets updated - onLocationChanged callback is triggered

Comment: Hey can you tell me for what purpose you have used RouteEntity & RoutePoint? I am stuck at that point.

Comment: This is just my internal wrapper around GeoPoint. I just need few more fields to store additional info (which is not used in this example). So for the simplicity, you can assume that `RouteEntity.RoutePoint` = `GeoPoint` and `mPoints` = `ArrayList<GeoPoint>`

Comment: I got the path but its not drawing properly. I have edited my question and added the draw method in it. Please kindly take a look on it..

Comment: Well, I have couple of comments: 1) It is better to use separate overlay to draw the path, but I don't see reasons why your solution wouldn't work, so this is just my preference 2) It is extremely bad idea to allocate memory in `draw()` - move your Paint allocations away of `draw()` 3) Increase stroke with to at least 10 px so you can actually see your path :) 4) Optimize `draw()` by skipping shadow passes. Just `return` when `shadow == true`

Comment: Thanks for your quick and kind response. I will follow your comments and hope it works.

Comment: Hi, I am done with the routes but getting one simple problem that i have edited in my question can you please help me if you have any idea.

Comment: are you calling `close()` method for your path? If so - this is the reason why the last point is connected to the first point

Comment: No I am not calling close method. also i have added my whole ItemizedOverlay class. If you can figure out any problem or mistake please let me know.